# If statements in java

Tags: java

This may be a simple question but...

In java is it possible to check if an integer for example is equal to one or another values without repeating the variables check..

e.g. This should work

```
int n = 0;
if ((n == 1) || (n == 2)) {
//do stuff
}
```

but is it possible to create something like this?

```
int n = 0;
if (n == 1 || 0) {
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: you could write a method that compare, in a for, until you get any true Value.
I don't know the Java sintax to write it. You shall pass the number to compare in a parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, you need to repeat the variable:

```
if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this directly in Java, but you could write a function that does this for you easily.

```
static boolean equalsAny(int n, int ... numbers)
{
   for (int num : numbers)
      if (n == num)
         return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then all you need to do is `if (equalsAny(n,1,2)) {/* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `case` statement.

```
switch(n) {
  case 1:
  case 2:
    // Do something.
    break;
}
```

This may sound facetious but I really mean it! The difference between a `case` and an `if` statement is often merely how the code evolves in the future. If you really only want to do something when a variable is set to a discrete number of values then you should be using a `case` statement or perhaps `enum`s.